# Simple knockout.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying the simplest possible example of knockout.js but it doesn't work (first and last names stay empty). I put my script tags after html tags that use binding and call ko.applyBindings after page loads. Alert works so the function fires. Any help?

```
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<script type="text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function AppViewModel() {
    alert("b");
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

$(window).load(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
</script>
```

EDIT
This problem is solved, but I have another one. What to do if I wanted to add first and last name simultaneously after clicking the button (not when inputs lose focus)?

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button"  >Add</a>

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable();
  this.lastName = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `$(window).load` to `$(document).ready`?

Comment: there are no changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatched quotes in your script tag. It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
```

You can actually drop the `type` attribute entirely and just do:

```
<script src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
```

and it'll still work fine.

Comment: @suue Try removing the `$(window).load`. I have it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ypoa7k0t/).

Comment: Still nothing. Can it be caused by the fact that I use velocity to create html?

Comment: @suue I don't know what velocity is. Open the console (hit F12) and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: Could you look at my edited post and see if you could help?

Comment: @suue I'm not sure what you mean by "add first and last name simultaneously". More importantly, rather than editing your current question, you should post a new question.

Comment: Right now when I put sth into input field it is immidiately shown below.I want to first fill both input fields and then "submit" them by clicking the button. Only after that I want them to be displayed below. If you won't be able to help, I will add a new question, then;)

Comment: @suue Ask another question and I'll try to help if I can. Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- I recommend loading jQuery *first*;
- Use `$(document).ready` (or equivalent: `$(function() ...`) instead of `$(window).load`;
- Fix the quotes in your `script` tag;
- Make sure that Knockout is being loaded (you don't use a CDN link, where you do have one for jQuery);

Here's proof that after those changes it can work:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    alert("b");
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
```